# Not able to call public pure functions of smart contract through reactjs

Tags: reactjs, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have written a smart contract which returns message hash after taking address, message, amount and nonce as an input. It is a public pure functions

```
 function _3_1getMessageHash(address _to, uint _amount, string memory _message, uint _nonce) public pure returns (bytes32)
    {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_to, _amount, _message, _nonce));
    }
```

I want to access this function through reactjs. I am able to access other functions of the smart contract but not this one.

```
function sign_1(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //console.log(project.methods.retailer.call().call());  // this works
  console.log(project.methods._3_1getMessageHash({sellerinfo}['sellerinfo'], quantity1,'test',0).call());                    // this doesn't 
  console.log(project.methods._3_1getMessageHash({sellerinfo}['sellerinfo'], quantity1,"test",0).send({from:{CurrentAccount}['CurrentAccount']})); //this doesn't either
  
}
```

please suggest the changes needed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a global function that you need to use anywhere, then I would recommend putting it into a component called GlobalFunctions or something like that. Then you need to make sure that you export and import each function you need.

```
 export function _3_1getMessageHash(address _to, uint _amount, string memory _message, uint _nonce) public pure returns (bytes32)
 {
     return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_to, _amount, _message, _nonce));
 }
```

Then where you need to use it:

```
import { _3_1getMessageHash } from '../../GlobalFunctions' // Whatever the relative path is
```

Finally you can change:

```
console.log(project.methods._3_1getMessageHash({sellerinfo}['sellerinfo'], quantity1,'test',0).call());
```

To:

```
console.log(_3_1getMessageHash({sellerinfo}['sellerinfo'], quantity1,'test',0));
```